# django paginate and sort large queryset

Tags: django

I want to hit the DB once per database search.

User can query the database and then paginate and sort the results.

the database contains 700 items.

django-debug-toolbar shows that sometimes queries takes too long.

currently i save the initial search results id in session and use this to build a queryset to sort and paginate the results.

I want to avoid this db query.

I was thinking on caching the queryset so other users would use the cached queryset and not hitting the db.

what do you think about this approach?
Is there something I miss?

```
    companiesID = request.session['selectedCompaniesIDs']

companies = Company.objects.filter(pk__in=companiesID).order_by(type).annotate(num_users=Count('users'))

cd = create_pagination(companies, page)
    PAGINATION_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 20

def create_pagination(results, page):
    paginator = Paginator(results, PAGINATION_RESULTS_PER_PAGE)

    try:
        res = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        res = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        res = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return res
```

1 MS:

> > SELECT `companies_company`.`id`, `companies_company`.`name`, 
> >         `companies_company`.`sector`, `companies_company`.`sub_sector`, `companies_company`.`num_of_employees`, `companies_company`.`address`,
> >     `companies_company`.`home_page`, `companies_company`.`career_url`, 
> >     `companies_company`.`city`, `companies_company`.`updating_date`, 
> >     COUNT(`companies_selectedusercompanies`.`user_id`) AS `num_users` FROM
> >     `companies_company`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies_selectedusercompanies`
> >     ON (`companies_company`.`id` =
> >     `companies_selectedusercompanies`.`company_id`) WHERE
> >     `companies_company`.`id` IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `companies_company`
> >     U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies_selectedusercompanies` U1 ON (U0.`id` =
> >     U1.`company_id`) GROUP BY U0.`id`, U0.`name`, U0.`sector`,
> >     U0.`sub_sector`, U0.`num_of_employees`, U0.`address`, U0.`home_page`,
> >     U0.`career_url`, U0.`city`, U0.`updating_date` ORDER BY NULL) GROUP BY
> >     `companies_company`.`id`, `companies_company`.`name`,
> >     `companies_company`.`sector`, `companies_company`.`sub_sector`,
> >     `companies_company`.`num_of_employees`, `companies_company`.`address`,
> >     `companies_company`.`home_page`, `companies_company`.`career_url`,
> >     `companies_company`.`city`, `companies_company`.`updating_date` ORDER
> >     BY `companies_company`.`sector` ASC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 160

11142 MS:

> SELECT `companies_company`.`id`, `companies_company`.`name`,
>   `companies_company`.`sector`, `companies_company`.`sub_sector`,
>   `companies_company`.`num_of_employees`, `companies_company`.`address`,
>   `companies_company`.`home_page`, `companies_company`.`career_url`,
>   `companies_company`.`city`, `companies_company`.`updating_date`,
>   COUNT(`companies_selectedusercompanies`.`user_id`) AS `num_users` FROM
>   `companies_company` LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies_selectedusercompanies`
>   ON (`companies_company`.`id` =
>   `companies_selectedusercompanies`.`company_id`) WHERE
>   `companies_company`.`id` IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `companies_company`
>   U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies_selectedusercompanies` U1 ON (U0.`id` =
>   U1.`company_id`) GROUP BY U0.`id`, U0.`name`, U0.`sector`,
>   U0.`sub_sector`, U0.`num_of_employees`, U0.`address`, U0.`home_page`,
>   U0.`career_url`, U0.`city`, U0.`updating_date` ORDER BY NULL) GROUP BY
>   `companies_company`.`id`, `companies_company`.`name`,
>   `companies_company`.`sector`, `companies_company`.`sub_sector`,
>   `companies_company`.`num_of_employees`, `companies_company`.`address`,
>   `companies_company`.`home_page`, `companies_company`.`career_url`,
>   `companies_company`.`city`, `companies_company`.`updating_date` ORDER
>   BY `companies_company`.`sector` ASC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 340

Comment: If your database has only 700 items and it takes too long to query every time the page is hit, there's something seriously wrong with your query.

Comment: something the result get back in couple of ms and something couple of seconds.

I can;t figure what makes this change.

Comment: This happens when I paginate to page != 1.
the queryset is equal.
The different is: paginator.page(page)

Comment: Can you show us your query / filter?

Comment: Please don't duplicate [your post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180715/)

Comment: Sometimes the queries take 1 ms and something 12 second.
what could be the reason for such gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that this is a known issue.
I will take the Facebook route and only show next and previous pages.

Comment: The issue was the annotate(num_users=Count('users'))
This does not change when user paginates.
Whats the preferred way to keep it between pages and not to calculate it every time?

Answer (score 0):

Such a simple query should not take any longer than a couple of ms for 700 records.
Please show us the raw SQL query generated by both requests (the one with page == 1 and the one with page > 1) and their timings.

Are your db indexes OK? Have you checked the timing of executing both raw sql queries using your DB client?